# WPF Path height to stretch to its container height

Tags: wpf, path, height, line

How can I make a vertical Line (Path) whose height adjusts with its container? If the horizontal StackPanel height changes (see code below), I want the vertical Line (Path) to adjust its height so that it stretches always the top and bottom of its containing StackPanel.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
     </StackPanel>
     <Path Data="M280,0 L280,300" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFE45737" Margin="50,0,0,0"  Width="2">
         <Path.Stroke>
             <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                 <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#0C9D9D9D"/>
                 <GradientStop Offset="0.996" Color="#0C9D9D9D"/>
                 <GradientStop Color="#FF9D9D9D" Offset="0.25"/>
                 <GradientStop Color="#FF9D9D9D" Offset="0.75"/>
              </LinearGradientBrush>
          </Path.Stroke>
      </Path>
</StackPanel>
```

With this code, the Path sticks with fixed height there although StackPanel height changes.

Comment: what do you mean by StackPanel height change? On maximizing and minimizing the window?

Comment: Not getting the question. If i put above code to xaml and run the app its stretches vertical line as per form size.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand clearly what you want but Path in `<ViewBox></Viewbox>`. Let me know it is what you want or add more information.